# Is there an integral representation of the multivariate beta function?

Tags: integration, beta-function

The [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) is defined by-

$\textstyle\displaystyle{B(x,y)=\int_{0}^{1}t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt}$

From this we can derive-

$\textstyle\displaystyle{B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}}$

Which also gives us the generalization-

$\textstyle\displaystyle{B(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\frac{\Gamma(x_1)\cdots\Gamma(x_n)}{\Gamma(x_1+\cdots+x_n)}}$

**Now I was wondering if there was an integral representation of the multivariate beta function just like there is for the beta function.**

I thought there would be one in the Wikipedia page but there isn't so I came here.

Comment: This may be useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459242/show-multivariate-beta-integrates-to-1

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash. I don't think that it really helps that much.