# $X,Y,Z$ are i.i.d $U(0,1)$. What is $P(X+Y+Z > 1)$?

Tags: probability

> Assume that $X,Y$ and $Z \sim U(0,1)$. Assume further $X,Y$ and $Z$ are mutually independent.
>   What is $P(X+Y+Z>1)$?

---

I've written down the density function of $X,Y$ and $Z$. I've drawn a picture. I understand the range of a new variable $U=X+Y+Z$ should be between $0$ and $3$. But I'm stuck on how to find the distribution of $U$.

Comment: I've written down the density function of $X$, $Y$ and $Z$. I've drawn a picture. I understand the range of a new variable $U = X + Y + Z$ should be between 0 and 3. But I'm stuck on how to find the distribution of $U$.

Comment: Oh, do you know $f_{X,Y,Z} = f_X f_Y f_Z$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769545/volume-of-t-n-x-i-ge0x-1-cdotsx-n-le1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(X+Y+Z\leq 1)=\mu\{(x,y,z)\in[0,1]^3:0\leq x+y+z\leq 1\}=\frac{1}{6}$$
since the middle term is the volume of a simple pyramid.

Answer (score 2):

The PDF of $U(0,1)$ is $f(x) = \chi_{[0,1]}(x)$. In other words, $P(X\le a) = a$ if $a\in[0,1]$ and $0$ else.
Now
$$P(X+Y+Z > 1) = 1 - P(X+Y+Z \le 1)$$
What do you know about the joint PDF of iid random variables?

---

We know $f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) = f_X(x) f_Y(y) f_Z(z)$ so in this case we have
$$P(U \le a) = \int_0^a \int_0^{a-x} \int_0^{a-x-y} 1\cdot 1\cdot 1 \ \mathrm dz \ \mathrm dy \ \mathrm dx$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I am struggling to see how you use $f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) = f_X(x) f_Y(y) f_Z(z)$ to get $P(U \le a) = \int_0^a \int_0^{a-x} \int_0^{a-x-y} 1\cdot 1\cdot 1 \ \mathrm dz \ \mathrm dy \ \mathrm dx$

Comment: The area we integrate over is the set
$$A:=\{(x,y,z)| x+y+z \le a\} \subset [0,1]^3$$
Thus $P(U\le a) = P(A) = \iiint_A f_{X,Y,Z}$

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to explicitly find the distribution of $U$, or to do any calculus.  The integral that AlexR gave is just the volume of a certain three-dimensional figure (a subset of the unit cube) which you should be able to find by basic geometry.