# Calculate the volume of a $k$-simplex in $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, volume, simplex, manifolds-with-boundary

> **Definition**
>
> If $x_0,...,x_n$ are $(k+1)$ affinely indipendent point of $\Bbb R^n$ (which means that the vectors $(x_1-x_0),...,(x_k-x_0)$ are linearly independent) then simplex determined by them is the set
> $$
> S:=\Biggl\{x\in\Bbb R^n: x=\alpha^i\vec v_i, \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\le1\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\alpha_i\ge0\,\,\,\text{for all}\,i\Biggl\}
> $$
> where $v_i:=(x_i-x_0)$ for each $i=1,\dots, k$.

So using the change of variables theorem (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3813429/find-the-volume-formula-of-a-simplex-proving-that-int-01-int-01-x-n-int/3814645#3814645) for details) it is possible to prove that the volume of a $n$-symplex $S$ in $\Bbb R^n$ is given by the formula
$$
\operatorname{vol}(S)=\Big|\frac{1}{n!}\det\big[(x_1-x_0),...,(x_n-x_0)\big]\Big|
$$
for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Moreover we know that any $k$-simplex is a compact convex smooth orientable $k$-manifold with corners (see theese three link -[I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4206438/prove-that-any-simplex-is-compact-and-convex), [II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4206996/prove-that-a-simplex-is-a-manifold-with-corners) and [III](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4222904/is-a-simplex-an-orientable-manifold-with-corners) - for more details) so that I ask if the same formula holds for any $k$-simplex in $\Bbb R^n$. So as proved in the link [II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4206996/prove-that-a-simplex-is-a-manifold-with-corners) any coordinate patch of $\mathcal S$ is equal to the composition of an affine map $f:\Bbb R^k\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ with a coordinate patch $\alpha:U\rightarrow V$ of the standard $k$-simplex $\mathcal E_k$ of $\Bbb R^k$ so that if $\{\phi_i:i=1,\dots,l\}$ is a partition of unity for $\mathcal S$ then $\{\phi_i\circ f:i=1,\dots,l\}$ is a partition of unity for $\mathcal E_k$; moreover the derivative of $\alpha$ is a square matrix so that by the Leibniz rule and by the Binet formula it follows that
$$
\operatorname{vol}\big(D(f\circ\alpha)\big):=\sqrt{\det\Big(\big(D(f\circ\alpha)\big)^T\cdot\big(D(f\circ\alpha)\big)\Big)}=\\
\sqrt{\det\Big((D\alpha)^T\cdot\big((Df)^T\cdot(Df)\big)\cdot(D\alpha)}=\\
\sqrt{\det\big(D\alpha)^T\cdot\det\big((Df)^T\cdot(Df)\big)\cdot\det(D\alpha)}=\\
\sqrt{\det\big((Df)^T\cdot(Df)\big)}\cdot\sqrt{\det\big(D\alpha)^T\cdot\det(D\alpha)}=\\
\sqrt{\det\big((Df)^T\cdot(Df)\big)}\cdot\sqrt{\det\big((D\alpha)^T\cdot(D\alpha)\big)}=\\
\operatorname{vol}\big(Df\big)\cdot\operatorname{vol}\big(D\alpha\big)=\operatorname{vol}(\vec v_1,\dots,\vec v_k)\cdot\operatorname{vol}\big(D\alpha\big)
$$
and thus
$$
\operatorname{vol}(\mathcal S)=\int_\mathcal S1=\sum_{i=1}^l\int_\mathcal S\phi_i=\sum_{i=1}^l\int_{\operatorname{int}U_i}\big(\phi_i\circ(f\circ\alpha_i)\big)\cdot\operatorname{vol}\big(D(f\circ\alpha_i)\big)=\\\operatorname{vol}(\vec v_1,\dots,\vec v_k)\cdot\sum_{i=1}^l\int_{\operatorname{int} U_i}\big((\phi_i\circ f)\circ\alpha_i\big)\cdot\operatorname{vol}\big(D\alpha_i\big)=\operatorname{vol}(\vec v_1,\dots,\vec v_k)\cdot\sum_{i=1}^l\int_{\mathcal E_k}(\phi_i\circ f)=\\
\operatorname{vol}(\vec v_1,\dots,\vec v_k)\cdot\int_{\mathcal E_k}1=\operatorname{vol}(\vec v_1,\dots,\vec v_k)\cdot\operatorname{vol}\big(\mathcal E_k\big)=\frac 1{k!}\operatorname{vol}(\vec v_1,\dots,\vec v_k)
$$
so that the statement holds. So I ask if my arguments are correct. Could someone help me, please?

**DETAILS ABOUT INTEGRATION ON MANIFOLDS**

If you do not understand completely the meaning of the symbols see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xomc.png) for explanations about the volume of a (compact) manifold.

Comment: What is volume of $Df$, etc.?

Comment: @TedShifrin The operator $D(\,)$ indicates the derivative of a function so that $\text{vol}\big(D(f\circ\alpha)\big)$ is the volume of the parallelopided generated by the column vectors of the derivative of $(f\circ\alpha)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Anyway I edited the question adding some details about the integration of a scalar function on a manifold: I hope now all is more clear.