# uniform distribution P(X>Y>Z) =?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, uniform-distribution

Let us assume $X,Y,Z$ three independent $U(0,1)$ random variables. Is it true that

$$P(Z < Y < X) = \int_{z = 0}^{1} \int_{y = z}^1 \int_{x=y}^1 dx dy dz $$

I know this is the approach for $P(Y < X)$, and I am wondering how to generalise this for an event with $n$ variables, e.g. $P(X_n < X_{n-1} < ... < X_1)$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/315300/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct way to do it.  And you can check your expression by doing the integral, which comes hout to have probability $1/n!$ for the $n$-variables case.

Comment: "this is the correct way to do it" One can also "do it" with no integral at all, using a symmetry argument which is well worth knowing.

Comment: Could you explain a little more about the symmetry argument?