# Question on how to compute the volume of an n-simplex

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, simplex

I was reading the post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769545/volume-of-t-n-x-i-ge0x-1-cdotsx-n-le1) and I understand how the method works. However, I'm not sure why the proof qualifies as a proof by *induction*. Based on my understanding, proof by induction works like this:

(1) Show that it is true when $n = 1$;

(2) Show that it is true when $n = k$;

(3) Show that it is true when $n = k+1$.

However, when the answer derives this equation:
\begin{align}V(T_n(1))&=\int_{x_n\le 1}\left(\int_{x_1+\cdots+x_{n-1}\le1-x_n}dx_1\cdots dx_{n-1}\right)dx_n\\
&=V(T_{n-1}(1))\int_{x_n\le1}\color{red}{(1-x_n)^{n-1}}dx_n=\frac1 nV(T_{n-1}(1))\end{align}

I'm not sure how it was *inducted*. I wrote out the cases when $n = 1,2,3$, but I could not prove a general case where $n = k$. Can someone please give me a hint on (1) how to prove the general case when $n = k$, and (2) do we actually need to prove the case where $n = k$?

Comment: Your idea of induction doesn't sound right. In the most common form, you assume it for $n=1$ or some base case, then assume it is true for $n=k$ and use it to show that it is true for $n=k+1$.

Comment: @OnceUponACrinoid This is where I learned about proof by induction: http://comet.lehman.cuny.edu/sormani/teaching/induction.html. Regardless of that, how does the post prove the equation by induction?