# What is the volume of the region $S =\{(x, y, z) : |x| + |y| + |z| ≤ 1\}$?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, volume

What is the  volume of the region $S =\{(x, y, z) : |x| + |y| + |z| ≤ 1\}$ ?

How  can  i find the volume

any hints /solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The region $S$ looks somewhat like this:

[image]

If you consider only the first octant, you have the simplex:

[image]

Due to symmetry, the volume of $S$ is $8$ times the volume of this simplex.

That is, $\operatorname{vol}(S)=8\,$[$\operatorname{vol}(\{(x,y,z): x,y,z\ge 0, x+y+z\le 1\})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769545/volume-of-t-n-x-i-ge0x-1-cdotsx-n-le1) $=8\times \frac1{6}=\frac 43$.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have to understand what $|x|+|y|+|z|=1$ means.

Obviously this equation is fully symmetric when changing the octants. Thus one can restrict to the first one and we get then $x+y+z=1$ instead. But this is nothing but the plane through the points $X=(1,0,0)$, $Y=(0,1,0)$, and $Z=(0,0,1)$.

Therefore your set $S$ is nothing but the octahedron, centered at the origin $O=(0,0,0)$, with circumradius $$r=\overline{OX}=\overline{OY}=\overline{OZ}=1$$ i.e. with edge length $$s=\overline{XY}=\overline{XZ}=\overline{YZ}=\sqrt2$$

Next one calculates the area $A_O$ of the triangle $OXY$ as $$A_O=\frac12\ \overline{OX}\ \overline{OY}=\frac12$$ Then the volume $V$ of the octahedral octant $OXYZ$ would be $$V=\frac13\ A_O\ \overline{OZ}=\frac16$$ Thus the searched for volume of the full octahedron is $$vol(S)=8\ V=\frac86=\frac43$$

You even could derive the total surface area of that octahedron. Let $M$ be the center of $X$ and $Y$. Thus $M=(\frac12, \frac12, 0)$. Then you'll have the distances
$$\overline{XM}=\overline{MY}=\frac12\ \overline{XY}=\frac{\sqrt2}2=\frac1{\sqrt2}$$
and
$$\overline{ZM}^2=\overline{XZ}^2-\overline{XM}^2=2-\frac12=\frac32$$
Then the area $A_Z$ of the triangle $XYZ$ becomes
$$A_Z=\frac12\ \overline{XZ}\ \overline{ZM}=\overline{XM}\ \overline{ZM}=\frac1{\sqrt2}\cdot \frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}=\frac{\sqrt3}2$$
and therefore finally 
$$\textit{surf}\,(S)=8\ A_Z=8\cdot\frac{\sqrt3}2=4\sqrt3$$

--- rk

Answer (score 0):

S is a diamond, to find the volume easily we can consider each octant, in which it is a tetrahedron of side length 1. So in each octant it has volume $\frac{1}{6}$ and thus the overall volume is $\frac43$.

Comment: @user376343 Good catch, just changed it!

Comment: The sides have to be specified, some of them have the length 1, but ..