# Why is the sum of x1...xn uniformly distributed over [0,1] equal to 1/n!?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Given x1, x2,...,xn is iid over a uniform [0,1], what is the probability that x1+x2+...+xn < 1?

Every explanation I've found seems to use simplex/n-dimension geometry which I can't understand. What's a probability/intuitive way of understand the result of $\frac{1}{n!}$?

My questionable logic is that 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 ... = 1 towards infinity. So for the sum of finite n < 1, the probability has to use that logic. So $\sum \frac{1}{2^i}$, then since order doesn't matter, multiply it by n to get $n\sum \frac{1}{2^i}$.

Now out of the (probably) many issues, the most first is that I can't get the probability of any point in a continuous distribution. That first 1/2 is based off of the mean.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It’s easier to see that the probability that $x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n$ is $1/n!$ But then it takes some effort to show that the two probabilities are the same.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Maybe worth spelling it out for the sake of it, then :)

Comment: @ClementC. Already shown in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/315300/321264.

Comment: Thanks for the sleuthing! @StubbornAtom