# Iterated integral, n-dimensions

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

say we have a function $g$ on an $n$-dimensional domain $[0,1]^n$, where g is defined as: $g(y_1, y_2, y_3, ... , y_n) = \mathbb{1}_{y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + ... + y_n \leq 1}$. That is, if the condition is met, $g = 1$, else $g = 0$. I would like to find $\int_{}g$.

But once we rewrite this as a series of $n$ iterated integrals, how do we proceed? How would we "fix" the other variables when taking a given integral given that the particular way the function is defined? it's not like we can just disregard all other $y_i$ when focusing on a specific integral

Comment: Go back to your multivariable calculus skills and do the cases $n=2$ and $n=3$ before tackling the general case.

Comment: Fubini allows you to write a multiple integral as an iterated integral. Of course, you can always rely on $\int_{[0,1]} \mathbb 1_E f = \int_E  f$ for any interval $E\subset [0,1]$.

Comment: As far as I’m concerned, Fubini allows you to write multiple integrals as iterated integrals. If you have further doubts, you should ask your professor.

Comment: I presume this is the Riemann integral?

Comment: When you are integrating with respect to $y_k$, all the other variables are treated as constants.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Volume).

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1718038/27978

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider a family of functions $g_{n, t} : [0, 1]^n \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g_{n, t}(y_1, \ldots, y_n) = 1_{y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_n \leq t}$. I claim that $\int\limits_{[0, 1]^n} g_{n, t}(y_1, \ldots, y_n) dy_1 \ldots dy_n = \frac{t^n}{n!}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_{> 0}$, $t \in [0, 1]$, and equals $0$ for $t < 0$.

We prove this by induction on $n$.

The base case here is $n = 1$. In this case, it is clear that the integral gives us $t = \frac{t^1}{1!}$ for $t \in [0, 1]$ as required and gives us $0$ for $t < 0$.

Now, we consider the inductive step. Write $n = k + 1$, and suppose $\int\limits_{[0, 1]^k} g_{k, t}(y_1, \ldots, y_k) dy_1 \ldots dy_k = \frac{t^k}{k!}$ for all $t \in [0, 1]$.

Then we have $\int\limits_{[0, 1]^{k + 1}} g_{k + 1, t}(y_1, \ldots, y_k, y_{k + 1}) dy_1 \ldots dy_k dy_{k + 1} = \int\limits_0^1 dy_{k + 1} \int\limits_{[0, 1]^k} g_{k + 1, t}(y_1, \ldots, y_k, y_{k + 1}) dy_1 \ldots dy_k$ by Fubini's theorem.

Now note that $g_{k + 1, t}(y_1, \ldots, y_k, y_{k + 1}) = 1_{y_1 + \cdots + y_k + y_{k + 1} \leq t}$. Note that $y_1 + \cdots + y_k + y_{k + 1} \leq t$ if and only if $y_1 + \cdots + y_k \leq t - y_{k + 1}$. Therefore, $1_{y_1 + \cdots + y_k + y_{k + 1} \leq t} = 1_{y_1 + \cdots + y_k \leq t - y_{k + 1}} = g_{k, t - y_{k + 1}}(y_1, \ldots, y_k)$. So we can rewrite the integral as $\int\limits_0^1 dy_{k + 1} \int\limits_{[0, 1]^k} g_{k, t - y_{k + 1}}(y_1, \ldots, y_k) dy_1 \ldots dy_k$. By the inductive hypothesis, we have

$\int\limits_{[0, 1]^k} g_{k, t - y_{k + 1}}(y_1, \ldots, y_k) dy_1 \ldots dy_k = \begin{cases} \frac{(t - y_{k + 1})^k}{k!} & y_{k + 1} \leq t \\
              0 & otherwise \end{cases}$

So the integral can be rewritten as $\int\limits_0^t dy_{k + 1} \frac{(t - y_{k + 1})^k}{k!}$. Make the $u$-substitution $u = t - y_{k + 1}$ to get the integral $\int\limits_0^t \frac{u^k}{k!} du = \frac{t^{k + 1}}{(k + 1) k!} = \frac{t^{k + 1}}{(k + 1)!}$. This is exactly what we needed to show. The proof is complete. $\square$

So in particular, for $g(y_1, \ldots, y_n) = g_{n, 1}(y_1, \ldots, y_n)$, we have $\int\limits_{[0, 1]^n} g(y_1, \ldots, y_n) dy_1 \ldots dy_n = \frac{1}{n!}$.

Comment: @Invincible It is straightforward to compute the integral for any fixed $n$ by following the procedure laid out in the induction step. It is also easy to guess by a simple scaling argument that for $t \in [0, 1]$, the integral should be proportional to $t^n$, and it is trivial to verify that the integral is $0$ for $t < 0$. Once you know it's proportional to $t^n$, you need a recurrence for the constant. You could try the induction with the claim that the integral is $c_n t^n$: if you do this, you'll see in the proof that $c_1 = 1$ and $c_{k + 1} = \frac{1}{k + 1} c_k$. This means $c_n = 1/n!$

Comment: @Invincible - there is no mystery in doing mathematics. You just have to play with it, that is, in this case. compute integral for some small value of $n$ like $n=1,2,3 ...$ and then notice a pattern and finally you prove it in general context.

Answer (score 0):

The integral can be estimated directly using Fubini's theorem:
$$\int^1_0\int^{1-x_1}_0\ldots\int^{1-x_1-\ldots-x_{n-1}}_0 dx_n\ldots dx_2 dx_1$$

for example, for $n=3$ we have
\begin{align}
\int^1_0\int^{1-x_1}_0(1-x_1-x_2)\,dx_2\,dx_1&=\int^1_0(1-x_1)^2-\frac12(1-x_1)^2\,dx_1\\
&=\frac12\int^1_0(1-x_1)^2\,dx_1\\
&=-\frac16(1-x)^3\Big|^1_0=\frac16
\end{align}

To proceed by induction, notice that each of the *inner* interated integrals is of the form
$$\frac1{k!} \int^{1-s}_0(1-s-t)^k\,dt=\frac{1}{(k+1)!}(1-s)^{k+1}$$

---

The Integral in the OP can also be estimated by more general methods:
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n_+}f(x_1+\ldots+x_n)x_1^{a_1-1}\cdot\ldots\cdot x^{a_n-1}_n\, dx_1\ldots dx_n = \frac{\Gamma(a_1)\cdot\ldots\Gamma(a_n)}{\Gamma(a_1+\ldots+a_n)}\int^\infty_0 f(t) t^{a_1+\ldots+a_n-1}\,dt\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}
where $\Gamma(t)=\int^\infty_0x^{t-1}e^{-x}\,dx$. The formula above  have been studied in MSE before. For example, in this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4359255/121671) the formula is obtained using (a) spherical coordinates, or (b) by linear transformations and Fubini's theorem.

The integral in the OP is of the form \eqref{one} with $f(t)=\mathbb{1}_{(0,1]}(t)$ and $a_1=\ldots =a_n=1$, in which case
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x_1+\ldots+ x_n)\,dx_1\ldots dx_n=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int^1_0t^{n-1}dt=\frac{1}{n!}$$

---